# Column matches from two seperate worksheets

Tags: excel

I am in need of your assistance with Excel.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with two worksheets, Shee1 and Sheet2

In Sheet1, I have the following columns
System
Table
Field
Mapped?

In Sheet2, I have the following columns
System
Table
Field

The same columns in both sheets except for the mapped column in sheet1.

How could I populate Sheet 1.Mapped with text Y where 
Sheet1.Table  and Sheet1.Field 
match
Sheet2.Table and  Sheet2.Field

Could this be done with a formula please? I am afraid I do not have access to VBA or to run macros due company policy.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Any of these might help: https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria OR http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/two-column-lookup.html OR https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/

Answer (score 1):

If You want to populate data in sheet1.Mapped where **(Sheet1.Table and Sheet1.Field)=(Sheet2.Table and Sheet2.Field)** then try below formula in sheet 1.Mapped:

=IF(AND(Sheet1!B:B=Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!C:C=Sheet2!C:C),"Yes","No")

Column B = Table & Column C = Field